# VS Code snippet to capitalize each word in filename

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a code snippet to capitalize each word in the filename base where the words are separated by dashes. While I know the words in the filename base will be separated by dashes, I don't know how may words to expect in the filename base. There could be zero or more dashes in my filename base. So, I could have:

```
name.extension
some-file-name.extension
yet-another-file-name.extension
and-yet-even-another-file-name.extension
```

etc., and I'd like these to become

```
Some File Name
Yet Another File Name
And Yet Even Another File Name
```

etc., respectively, in my code.

I've tried in an attempt just to get the first word to capitalize, but this only drops the first letter of my filename base, and leaves the rest unchanged:

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[\\w+]/${1:/capitalize}/}`

What am I missing?  How do I iterate with the snippets syntax?

Comment: Are u sure that your regexp work in VSCode?? It does not work for me, my VSCode search does not support it. Do you have some particular plugin installed?? Why do u want to complicate your life with regexp in VSCode, that is famous for its "Lone quantifier object" and "incomplete quantifier" errors ? You can transform your file in the desired way in several other easier ways (with or without a regexp)

Comment: oof: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80126. more oof: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109766. more oof: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134046

Comment: depending of your use case maybe [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) can be handy, you can add snippets in the templates

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in your answer about conditional transforms using this snippet body:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w+)|(\\W+)/${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g}
```

The conditional replacements are explained here: [snippets grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar).

```
                | '${' int ':+' if '}'
                | '${' int ':?' if ':' else '}'
                | '${' int ':-' else '}' | '${' int ':' else '}'
```

`${2:+ }` is an `if` transform.  If there is a group 2 insert a space.

`${2: }` is one of the two  `else` transforms from the last line above.  So  `${2: }` means if there is a capture group 2 do nothing but `else` (meaning there is no group 2) then insert a space.

The `g` flag makes the transform run as many times as it finds a match.  So whenever the `(\\W+)` part of your regex matches that means there was no group 1 (since you are using an alternate `|` in the regex and there was a group 2.  So how does your snippet work if you use the `${2: }` form?  You have to work through each **match**.

Using `some-file-name`:

The first match will be capture group 1 `some` and no capture group 2.  Now the entire transform gets applied to that match.  Group 1 gets capitalized  and since there is no group 2 on the first match, the `else`  `${2: }` is triggered and a space is inserted.

Then the next match will be no group 1 and a group 2 of `-`.  The replacement part of the transform will not capitalize anything (since there is no group 1).  The `${2: }` will insert nothing (since there is a group 2).  But it seems to be inserting group 2 - which is non-obvious to me and actually seems like a bug.  It is operating as if it read: if group 2, insert group 2, else (no group 2) insert a space.  That is a little surprising to me.  In any case, it explains why the `-` which is matched (in the 2nd/4th/6th/etc. match) inserts the group 2 `-`.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the following `body` it works

- a literal `.` and extension => ignore
- catch a possible `-` followed by text until a `.` or `-`
- substitute the `-` by a space and capitalize the word

```json
"body": "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\.\\w+$)|(-?)([^-.]+)/${2:+ }${3:/capitalize}/g}"
```

It works for `${TM_FILENAME}` and `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}`

---

**Edit**

The examples all contain extensions but it turns out that `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` strips the extension.

I have tested the snippet with `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}` and the examples.

An update of the snippet body:

```json
"body": "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(-?)([^-]+)/${1:+ }${2:/capitalize}/g}"
```

Answer (score -1):

**I managed to get this to work with the following, but I don't understand why it works.  Please edit this response if you can help out.**

This will return the desired string:

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\\w+)|(\\W+)/${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g}`

Explanation:

- `TM_FILENAME_BASE` is a Code snippets variable.  It doesn't include the extension, so we don't need to worry about writing a regex expression to get rid of that; we get to start with (e.g.) `some-file-name`.
- `(\\w+)|(\\W+)` defines two regex search groups:

  - `(\\w+)` returns any group of alphanumeric text
  - `(\\W+)` returns any group of non-alphanumeric text
- `${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g` capitalizes the first group, and *if it finds a second group* will remove and replace the dashes with a space.  The final /g switch makes the entire expression greedy.

Here's the bit I don't get: I don't understand why I need the `+` in `${2:+ }`.  If I use `${2: }`, though (no `+`), the return value comes out as `Some -File -Name`  (note also final trailing space in addition to the other unexpected  aspects of the return value).

Comment: if you don't understand where did you get the `${2:+ }` from

Comment: `g` is not greedy

Comment: Not sure why a working answer is downvoted.  @rioV8, First comment: I got the `${2:+ }` from reading through others' snippets.  My use of it is a separate beast from my understanding of it.  Second comment: can you revise the answer above to add some constructive input?  For example, what is `g`?  Feel free to revise your original answer if you prefer.  Yours also works, but the search for the file extension is extraneous (there's no extension returned by `TM_FILENAME_BASE`), and you do not provide any explanation   for how you arrived at your result.  Thanks!

Comment: if `TM_FILENAME_BASE` does not contain the extension why do your examples in the question ALL have extensions

Comment: why do these other snippets not explain the `g` and the `+`